# forEach of undefinied EJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, ejs

Hola estoy programando un proyecto que involucra bases de datos y resulta que quiero hacer una lista con todos los usuarios registrados con un forEach pero no me deja agregarlo y me lanza este error:
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
Acá les dejo la linea de código que me da problemas:

```
            <% user.forEach(user => { %>
                <h5><%=user.nombre%> </h5>
            <% }); %>
```

Pd. Esa variable "user" la saco de mi BD MongoDB al igual que nombre.

Comment: user debe ser un tipo array para poder usar forEach, ojo un array, no un html collection ni algo parecido. O quizá la data se este cargando despues de tu ciclo y por eso falla.

Comment: como puedo saber que tipo de array es osea yo lo defini como un string

Comment: como le pasas las variables a la template en el método `render`?

Comment: primero lo que hago es sacar el modelo y procesarlo para que su guardado sea efectivo, por medio de passport y passport lo defino en el index.js y asi puedo llamar a todas las funciones de mi modelo en los ejs

Comment: Hace falta mucha más información. Sólo has colocado la linea que te da el problema, pero eso no es suficiente. Considera leer [mcve]. En todo caso, habría que ve cómo construyes tu variable `user` en tu `backend`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui esta mi funcion, y en lugar de usar tu user use data, que es la variable que retoma los datos de result para ser utilizados en la vista ejs de la misma forma que tu tienes el forEach

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res, next){
           
   var user =  req.session.user,
   userId = req.session.userId;
   console.log('ddd='+userId);
   if(userId == null){
      res.redirect("/login");
      return;
   }

   var sql="SELECT * FROM `news`";

   db.query(sql, function(err, result){
      res.render('dashboard.ejs', {data:result});    
      console.log(result)
   });       
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido :) . Puedes por favor editar tu respuesta y poner el código, en **formato código**. Esto hará que sea más fácil de ver y copiar!

Comment: Listo, queda editada la publicacion